# Why validate redirect_uri in token call (code to token exchange)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I haven't seen a good explanation online as to the specific security exploit that this protects from.

Assuming the OAuth provider validates the redirect_uri in the initial call to the authorization endpoint, why then must the provider also validate the redirect_uri in the subsequent backchannel call to the token endpoint (auth code to token exchange)?

Even the spec only mentions [Authorization Code Redirection URI Manipulation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6) as a vulnerability that would be prevented by a check in the auth endpoint alone.

[This explanation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-validation/) does not link to an actual vulnerability or exploit:
"As an added measure of security, the server should verify that the redirect URL in this request matches exactly the redirect URL that was included in the initial authorization request for this authorization code."

Comment: Found a satisfactory explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653421/why-does-oauth-rfc-require-the-redirect-uri-to-be-passed-again-to-exchange-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does OAuth RFC require the redirect\_uri to be passed again to exchange code for token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653421/why-does-oauth-rfc-require-the-redirect-uri-to-be-passed-again-to-exchange-code)